# Tapestry Runtime Exception "multiple active template data is not allowed"

Tags: tapestry

Being new to Tapestry I find myself at a loss to what certain exceptions really mean.  Tapestry documentation and google searches are limited.  Yes I am supporting a legacy application for the moment but we will be upgrading.  In the mean time, can someone shed some light on what exactly the following exception means and what might cause it ( in general ).  While I know you won't have the exact answer, I'm looking for a general direction or idea of what might cause this.

Tapestry Version:5.3.8
Tomcat:8

```
Machine: xxx-xxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx
Mode: Production

User ID: xxxxxxx
Patient ID: xxxxxxx
Practice: xxxxx xxxxx xxxxx xxx xx
For: xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
User Role: xxxx xxxxx xxxxxx


Request Path: https://www.somewebsite.net/app/dashboard/chart.component.form
XMLHttpRequest: true

org.apache.tapestry5.runtime.ComponentEventException
multiple active template data is not allowed. appUserId=xxxxxxx patientAppUserId=xxxxxx
    context
    eventType
    location
org.apache.tapestry5.ioc.internal.OperationException
multiple active template data is not allowed. appUserId=xxxxxxx patientAppUserId=xxxxx
    location
    trace
org.apache.tapestry5.runtime.ComponentEventException
multiple active template data is not allowed. appUserId=xxxxxx patientAppUserId=xxxxxx
    context
    eventType
    location
java.lang.RuntimeException
multiple active template data is not allowed. appUserId=xxxxx patientAppUserId=xxxxxxx
        com.ageology.amsa.services.practice.PhysicalExamTemplateService.getDefaultTemplateId(PhysicalExamTemplateService.java:182)
        $IPhysicalExamTemplateService_153b979dc40fb2.getDefaultTemplateId(Unknown Source)
        $IPhysicalExamTemplateService_153b979dc3ec0c.getDefaultTemplateId(Unknown Source)
        com.ageology.amsa.components.physiciandashboard.PhysExamComponent.initData(PhysExamComponent.java:222)
        com.ageology.amsa.components.physiciandashboard.PhysExamComponent.onSuccessFromPhysicalExamForm(PhysExamComponent.java:234)
        com.ageology.amsa.components.physiciandashboard.PhysExamComponent.dispatchComponentEvent(PhysExamComponent.java)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tapestry's ComponentEventException is just wrapping the Runtime exception thrown by your PhysicalExamTemplateService.java:182, so you'll need to look there to see what the real problem is.